# How to show page number in "page X of Y" format?

Tags: google-sheets

I can select to show page number in Google Sheets print options. However, what I want is to have "Page X of Y", e.g. "Page 1 of 5".

Is it at all possible to do in Google Sheets?

Comment: Seems to be still a missing feature by April 2020.

Answer (score 2):

It's not completely automated like excel but this is the best shortcut i could find.

print settings -> headers and footers -> edit custom field -> click "page number b"

Now it should look like this in green. [PageB]

Count how many pages there are. If they're 5 you type in "of 5"

It shoud look like "[PageB] of 5"

The "of 5" part stays the same but it will change the page count per page so it looks correct.

Hope this helps~

Answer (score 1):

Under Print > Headers & footers there is an option to add Page numbers. It is a field that will increment as additional pages are printed. As far as I am aware there is no equivalent field for the total number of pages (in Sheets), but this may be added (along with `of`) through EDIT CUSTOM FIELDS. There `Page` or `Pg` may also be added, either in the same way or by editing the field choice (click on the left hand icon).

[image: ![Print screen]

The *previous* screen should display the total number of pages to expect (top left).

Comment: This is a useful workaround, but you have to remember to check the footer every time you print the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

After adding the page numbers to the footer (or header), double click the footer and after the page number add "of" then go to the "Insert Tab - Page numbers - Page count. Its done.